Can I narrow the instance of a class to that of a similar class through type narrowing of its members?
I need to assert that the instance of a certain TypeScript class which possess a nullable member can satisfy a different class which possess a member with the same name and type, except it's not nullable.
I thought that narrowing the member value could do what I need but, while the member itself gets narrowed, the class instance is still typed as if the member could have a value of null.
declare class SomeClass {
  _someProp: string | null;
}

declare class SomeOtherClass {
  _someProp: string;
}

function SomeFunction(request: SomeClass) {
  if (!request._someProp) return;

  request._someProp satisfies string
  request satisfies SomeOtherClass
}

Type 'SomeClass' does not satisfy the expected type 'SomeOtherClass'.
  Types of property '_someProp' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Playground
In the example above, and more generally in TypeScript, can I narrow the instance of a SomeClass to satisfy SomeOtherClass?

Make it a type predicate?

@jonrsharpe that can work in the use case I had in mind (check if a NextAuthRequest instance holds a valued session when passing it as an argument)

You want the feature requested at ms/TS#42384 but it's not part of the language. You could emulate it by writing a guardObjByProp type guard function as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz yes, I can do with type predicates. also, I'll subscribe to that feature request (and probably leave a note about it in my code...)

TypeScript does not generally narrow the apparent type of an object in response to narrowing the apparent type of one of its properties. The only time that happens is if the object is of a discriminated union type and the property being checked is a discriminant property.  But in your case, SomeClass isn't a union type at all, let alone a discriminated one.  So checking args._someProp narrows args._someProp but unfortunately it doesn't narrow args at all.
This is a missing feature of TypeScript as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#42384.  Until and unless that is implemented, you'll need to work around it.  One workaround would be to write a general user-defined type guard function to narrow objects by checking their properties, as shown here:
function guardObjByProp<T extends object, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(
  obj: T, key: K, guard: (x: T[K]) => x is V): obj is T & Record<K, V> {
  return guard(obj[key])
}

Now if you call guardObjByProp(obj, key, guard) and it returns true, the type of obj will be narrowed from T to T & Record<K, V> where K is the type of key and V is the guarded type of guard.  You can rewrite SomeFunction like:
function SomeFunction(args: SomeClass) {
  if (!guardObjByProp(args, "_someProp", x => x !== null)) return;
  args._someProp satisfies string // okay
  args satisfies SomeOtherClass // okay
}

Where x => x !== null is inferred to be a type predicate function of type (x: string | null) => x is string. So when !guardObjByProp(args, "_someProp", x => x !== null)) returns true, args is narrowed to SomeClass & {_someProp: string} which is assignable to SomeOtherClass and your code succeeds.
Note that the first change of if (!request._someProp) would be to if (!guardObjByProp(args, "_someProp", x => !!x), since you're doing truthiness narrowing, but truthiness narrowing on string | null doesn't make a valid type guard function.  See the implementation of inferred type predicates at microsoft/TypeScript#57465, specifically the part titled "this is a gentle nudge away from truthiness footguns". If you want to distinguish string from null, you should compare directly to null and not deal with the added wrinkle that "" is a falsy string.
Playground link to code

I hope I'll remember the part about truthiness vs null narrowing...
